# Backbone collect reset not triggering event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a method in my collection that performs a filter.

```
filterByCategory: function() {
    this.collection.reset(this.collection, {silent: true});

    var filterCategory = this.filterCategory;
    var filtered = _.filter(this.collection.models, function (item) {
        return Date.parse(item.get("category")) < filterCategory;
    });

    this.collection.reset(filtered);
}
```

In my initialise function I then have listen to the reset event but this never gets called.

```
this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
```

I've checked and made sure that my collection is definitely being filter correctly.  Also if I add `this.render` underneath `this.collection.reset(filtered)` that also doesn't work.

One thing I can think of is that with the collection I'm currently working with my filters either return **every item** in the collection or **none of the items** in the collection.  Could it be that the reset event only gets fired if you pass it a subset of your collection that is has at least one item in it but not every item in it?

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/yt7wqmqv/